# Angular TypeError: name.replace is not a function for ng-style

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

I'm new to angular and keep getting the following error in the console `TypeError: name.replace is not a function`. I'm not sure what's exactly causing it, but it seems to be caused by the `ng-style` statement and maybe something to do with the camelCase?

The part I don't understand is why `ng-style="isFrontView() || !matches && {'display': 'none'}"` throws the error, but `ng-style="!isFrontView() || !matches && {'display': 'none'}"` doesn't throw the error.

In an attempt to remedy the situation I tried removing the camelCase from the function name and went all lowercase. I also attempted to use `!!isFrontView()`, but neither seemed to remove the error message.

Do anyone know what is the cause of this error message and a potential fix?

[image: Error Message]

HTML Template:

```
<div class="system-view">
    <div class="controller-container fill" id="systemView1" ng-style="isFrontView() || !matches && {'display': 'none'}">
        <canvas id="canvasLayer-shell" data-layername="front" width="617" height="427"></canvas>
        <i ng-if="!matches" class="fa fa-repeat toggle-view" ng-click="changeView()" ng-touch="changeView()"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="controller-container fill" id="systemView2" ng-style="!isFrontView() || !matches && {'display': 'none'}">
        <canvas id="canvasLayer-shell" data-layername="back" width="617" height="427"></canvas>
        <i ng-if="!matches" class="fa fa-undo toggle-view" ng-click="changeView()" ng-touch="changeView()"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Backend Code:

```
$scope.frontView = true;
$scope.matches = true;

$scope.isFrontView = function() {
   return $scope.frontView;
};

$scope.changeView = function() {
    $scope.frontView = !$scope.frontView;
};
```

P.S. Even with the console error everything still functions normally.

Comment: Side note: Why dont you just use ng-show/ng-hide nstead of ng-style expression to hide the element.

Comment: @PSL The application is currently setup to draw to both canvas' so they must stay in the DOM.

Comment: If you use ng-show/ng-hide. they will stay in DOM, unlike ng-if.

Comment: @PSL Thanks for the clarification. I will use ng-hide/ng-show. But, I'm still curious as to what's causing the error above and why `!isFrontView()` works. Will be helpful to know if I have to apply a dynamic style.

Comment: Issue is ofcourse becaue the value of the ng-style attr will be boolean in stead of string eg true. and it internally calls jqlite element.css with boolean in stead of string and boolean does not have replace function. It is for string. You could do `'' + (isFrontView() || !matches && {'display': 'none'})` as well

Comment: @PSL Thanks. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your potential issue is due to the incorrect usage of `ng-style`. [`ng-style` sets a watcher on the expression](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngStyle.js#L50) and sets the [element's style with the help of jquery/jqlite `element.css`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/9efb0d5ee961b57c8fc144a3138a15955e4010e2/src/jqLite.js#L598). And Inside `element.css` css attribute (`name`) is converted to the standard camel casing ([which uses regex string replace](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/9efb0d5ee961b57c8fc144a3138a15955e4010e2/src/jqLite.js#L147)). In your specific case the expression evaluated to boolean (`true`) instead of an object ([`ng-style` does this for each property](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngStyle.js#L52)) and *boolean* does not have `replace` property (which is available on a *string* object) and hence it fails. You can test this by converting your expression to evaluate to a string by using string concatenation.

i.e `ng-style="'' + (isFrontView() || !matches && {'display': 'none'})"`

Looking at the expression all you need it to hide and show the element, you could well make use of [`ng-show`/`ng-hide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) directives to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the expression evaluated returns the wrong type.

Expression evaluated:

```
ng-style="$vm.getStyles()"
```

must return an object literal:

```
return { order: -1 };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but I might help others that have the same issue  like me.In my case the error is **a.replace is not a function** and finally I found the reason. It was happening due to ng-style and the expression was `data-ng-style="isCompare==true ? {'max-height':'423'} : ***' '***  ....` that space between single qoutes  caused the error.After removing space the error went away.