# Angular js set Openlayers map window element dimensions dynamically

Tags: angularjs, openlayers-3

I have an Openlayers 3 map in an element from a directive that needs to resize correctly when the user resizes the browser.

```
wmm.directive('tchOlMap', ['$window', function ($window) {
var hgt = ($window.innerHeight - 102);
var wdth = ($window.innerWidth - 400);

var MAP_DOM_ELEMENT_ID = 'tchMap';

return {

    //restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    //replace: true,

    template: '<div id="' + MAP_DOM_ELEMENT_ID + '" class="full-height" style="height: '+hgt+'px; width: '+wdth+'px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border:2px solid;  border-color: #76AF75"></div>',

    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
     scope.isCollapsed = false;  

      var w = angular.element($window);
        scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
        return { 'h': w.height(), 'w': w.width() };
        };

    scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {

        scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
        scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
        console.log(newValue.w+' '+newValue.h);
        hgt = newValue.h;
        wdth = newValue.w;

        scope.style = function () {

            return { 
                'height': (newValue.h - 102) + 'px',
                'width': (newValue.w - 400) + 'px' 
            };
        };

    }, true);

    w.bind('resize', function () {
        scope.$apply();
    });
```

I can see in the console that it is returning the updated dimensions but the values are not being applied to the element I'm stuck as to how to apply the dimensions to the element - Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a static value in the template, you should change your template to use the values available in your scope.

```
template: '<div id="' + MAP_DOM_ELEMENT_ID + '" class="full-height" ng-style="style"></div>'
```

And then just define and update the style in your link function storing all style required in scope.style property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried this but now I'm getting this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549494/angular-typeerror-name-replace-is-not-a-function-for-ng-style

Comment: scope.style should be an object containing the style that you require, in your controller as it is in the question, scope.style stores a function (probably that's the error), just update your controller to store the object with the css definition and should work, I think.

Comment: Thanks @pedromarc. I declared the style object at the start of the link function and then passed the styles into it in the $watch function.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final working code thanks to @pedromarc

```
wmm.directive('tchOlMap', ['$window', function ($window) {

var MAP_DOM_ELEMENT_ID = 'tchMap';

return {
    //restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    //replace: true,

    template: '<div id="' + MAP_DOM_ELEMENT_ID +'" class="full-height" ng-style="style"></div>',

    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.style = {};

      scope.isCollapsed = false;  

      var w = angular.element($window);
        scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
        return { 'h': w.height(), 'w': w.width() };
        };

       scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {

        scope.style = { 
                'height': (newValue.h - 102) + 'px',
                'width': (newValue.w - 400) + 'px',
                'padding' : 0 + 'px',
                'margin' : 0 + 'px',
                'border': 2 + 'px solid',
                'border-color' : '#76AF75'
            };

    }, true);    
    w.bind('resize', function () {
       scope.$apply();
      });
```